# Since 3.62 can be divided evenly by .1 does that mean it is a muliple of .1?

Tags: unit-of-measure

Medicare was billed 3.62 mg of a drug expressed with a code description of .1 mg per unit (in other words we billed 37 units of the code, because we rounded up).  Medicare says if the dosage given is not a multiple of the number provided in the code description, the provider shall round up to the nearest whole number in order to express then number as a multiple. I'm not sure if we should round up or down.  I think 3.62 is a multiple of .1 but when you divide 3.62 by .1 there's a remainder of .2.  Even though there's a remainder it is evenly divisible.  So I'm confused.

Comment: $3.62/0.1=36.2\approx 36$

Comment: What is the definition of a multiple?

Comment: $3.62=36\times0.1+0.02$.  Since $0.02>0$, it gets rounded to $0.1$ (the rules laid out by medicare) so $3.62$ is rounded to $3.6+.1=3.7$

Comment: What do you mean by "evenly divisible"?

Answer (score 0):

That translates to a multiple

$$
k = \lceil m / 0.1 \text{mg} \rceil
$$
and a dosage
$$
m' = k \cdot 0.1 \text{mg}
$$

For your example $m = 3.62 \text{mg}$ we get $k = 37$ and $m' = 3.7 \text{mg}$.

The remainder $0.02 \text{mg} = (1/5) \cdot 0.1 \text{mg}$ was rounded up to a full unit of $0.1 \text{mg}$.